# MySQL INSERT SET with PASSWORD()

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, mysqljs

```
req.body = {
  username: 1,
  password: 1
}

conn.query('INSERT INTO user SET username = ?, password = PASSWORD(?)',
  [req.body.username, req.body.password])
```

When using [MySQL for Nodejs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), we can do the above to insert an user.

However, the following is much cleaner (allows more fields to be set by adding to `req.body` without altering the code):

```
conn.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', req.body)
```

But how do we solve the problem of needing to call `PASSWORD()` on the `req.body.password` field?

Comment: conn.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', req.body.username, PASSWORD(req.body.password)); , check if this working for you

Comment: @Deep `PASSWORD()` is a MySQL function, not a JS function. Your code will give `PASSWORD` is undefined.

Comment: You should not use MySQL's PASSWORD function for your application.. MySQL's PASSWORD function is designed for the authentication system in MySQL Server   read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password ) ... Your better off searching for a JavaScript library that supports bcrypt.( https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+bcrypt )

Comment: @RaymondNijland didn't notice that, thanks. Seems like i can just switch to `SHA2` though https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2

Comment: SHA2 isn't really safe without using a salt that is atleast 32 chars . There are rainbow tables containing a lot off SHA2 strings.. Besides SHA2 is a fast hashing algorithm that also runs extremely fast op GPU's (bruteforcing +200 Billion hashes per second on hardware that is over 5 years old).. Bcrypt is designed to be a slow algorithm and also it runs slow on GPU's besides Bcrypt generates hashes that are different each time even on the same data meaning the cracker/hacker can't use rainbow tables.

Comment: @RaymondNijland why does SSL cert use SHA2 then? What's the difference between SSL cert and password hashing that makes password requiring greater security?

Comment: When you generate a SSL cert you generate one with a random generated salt.. some SSL program's (like PuttyGen) also use random mouse positions to use as seed for the salt.. i already said that SHA2 is safe when you use a salt doensn't matter when you hash passwords for a application or use it in a cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, You can not use a `MySQl`  function like this inside a JavaScript code.

The first approach which you are following is the only way which you have to follow.

```
req.body = {
  username: 1,
  password: 1
}

conn.query('INSERT INTO user SET username = ?, password = PASSWORD(?)',
  [req.body.username, req.body.password])
```